# Windows 7 Desktop was "reset"

Tags: windows-7

I'm not sure if this site is the right place for this type of question, but I give it a try. If it's the wrong place please tell me.

Today `Win 7 Pro 32-Bit` did something strange. I try to explain this as best as I can but because I don't have an English version of Windows there maybe other terms.

I booted the system and while Windows was loading I put a non-bootable CD in the drive. The result was that my `Desktop was set to default`, which means `all files, directories and custom links disappeared` and the background was reset to the default. Only links of installed Software are still left.

Furthermore the directories `Picture, Videos, Documents, Downloads` etc. are empty, if I navigate to them with the Startmenu. I had a look with the Explorer and C:\user\myusername\documents etc. contains all the data.

I opened an Office file and Word was asking me how to treat this file, like the first time loaded.

I really don't know what happend. The only guess I have is that the filesystem crashed.

My questions are

- What happend? I know this is a real broad question but I really would like to know what causes this.
- How can I go back to the configuration before the "crash"?

I tried the "repair" function but without success. And because I disabled "restore points", the only one I have is from the Win 7 installation.

Comment: Look at C:\Users Are you by chance logged into a `TEMP` profile?

Comment: Now you've learned why you don't disable restore points. ;)   If you want to know what happened, try looking a the logs in the Event Viewer.

Comment: This is probably unrelated to the CD being there and just a coincidence. Try rebooting first - it sounds like you got logged in with a temporary profile because it had an issue loading something. If rebooting doesn't fix it, let us know and I'll give you some instructions on how to copy things over from the old profile.

Comment: reboot to machine and when you see BIOS, hold on `F8` key to get advance boot menu. When you see it, try selecting `Last known good configuration` option. Once booted, try logging and see.

Comment: @nhinkle I'm logged in with my admin username.

Comment: @AzkerMohamed I tried this boot option but the situation remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

What username are you logged in as currently? Sounds like you're logged in as a different or new user. It might be that when you logged in this time, you mistakenly entered a new username and Windows created a new user for that.

Reboot and try logging in as the correct user.

Comment: I'm logged in as usual with my admin username. A reboot didn't change anything.